# Disable front facing camera in application created with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-plugins, front-camera

My Sencha touch hybrid application provides user the ability to take photos from application using the device native camera with `Cordova` plugin. But I want to `disable the front facing camera`. User should not be able to switch between front and rear cameras. I tried `cameraDirection` values `1` and `0` but that only helps to switch between Front and rear cameras and not to disable the front camera. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, correctOrientation: true, cameraDirection: 0 });
```

Comment: Are you using `cordova-plugin-camera` ?

Comment: @RohitSharma yes

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution with below options:

```
cameraDirection: Choose the camera to use (front- or back-facing). Defined in navigator.camera.Direction (Number)

Camera.Direction = {
    BACK : 0,      // Use the back-facing camera
    FRONT : 1      // Use the front-facing camera
};
```

**Reference:** https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova/camera/parameter/cameraOptions.html

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I am using. Please check. It is same as what you suggested right?